# Line pattern fill missing when exporting as SVG in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, svg

When exporting from Print Layout as a `.svg`-file in QGIS the line fill pattern disappears of all polygons. How can I stop this happening?

The problem doesn't occur when exporting as an image file or PDF, however, I would like the map to be in SVG format to edit the layers further in Inkscape.

Comment: Can't Inkscape open PDF? The GIMP can.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

It had happened to me on QGIS 3.18 as well, the line pattern fill for polygons was missing when exporting as SVG.

Example in the Print Composer

[image: print_composer]

Example of exported SVG (viewed via Google Chrome)

[image: export1]

In this case, I would probably follow what is mentioned in the Infobox when exporting as SVG from the Print Composer

> The SVG export function in QGIS has several problems due to bugs and
> deficiencies in the underlying Qt SVG library. In particular, there
> are problems with layers not being clipped to the map bounding box.
>
> If you require a vector-based output file from QGIS it is suggested that
> you try exporting to PDF if the SVG output is not satisfactory.

So, the workaround is to export it as a PDF and afterwards convert it into SVG in the vector editor of your choice. In my case, Adobe Illustrator did the job, see image below (viewed via Google Chrome).

[image: export2]

Comment: Great! Just to add an OpenSource alternative to Adobe Illustrator, you could also use Inkscape - https://inkscape.org